# Script to dynamically change desktop background

Tags: windows-7

I have a requirement to generate a visualisation (think pie chart) and set it as the desktop wallpaper on a Windows 7 corporate network.

I'm a web/mac guy, so I am guessing at the following implementation (assume I know nothing).

1. Write a script and get the network admins to distribute it to everyones "Startup" folder.
2. The script will download an image from: `http://visualisation-server/desktop.jpeg?username={USERNAME}&psk={PSK}`, where `USERNAME` is their domain username and `PSK` is a custom variable in their AD profile.
3. The downloaded image is then set as their desktop.

For those whom don't login/out regularly can is there a scheduler that I can use?

The PSK isn't a deal breaker as although the visualisation is custom for everyone, it doesn't need to be secure.

So my question. Is this possible? If so, what languages/technology do I need to use?

Many thanks,
Si

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing I could find was "Windows 7 RSS Themes". http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/rss-theme-faq

You cannot send the username/psk unless you prepare a different theme for each user. This is possible in my situation.

We've decided to proceed with a TideSDK minimal app to do the same thing.